# Why is my web3 "signTransaction" function hanging?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to send a transaction to a custom chain/RPC using the web3 javascript library. When I try to use the `web3.eth.signTransaction` function, my program hangs and doesn't continue.
Here is my code. The last log that shows up in the terminal (I'm using Nodejs) is "signing transaction...", so I assume the signTransaction function is the problem.

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
import WalletConnectProvider from '@walletconnect/web3-provider'
...
      console.log('connecting to private chain...')
      const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
        rpc: {
          74: 'private chain RPC is here...',
        },
        chainId: 74,
      })
      console.log('connecting to web3...')
      const web3 = new Web3(provider)
      const txParams = {
        to: 'wallet address is here',
        value: 0,
        gasPrice: '10',
        gas: '21010',
        data: Web3.utils.toHex(publicKey),
        chainId: 74,
        from: 'wallet address is here',
      }
      console.log('signing transaction...')
      console.table(web3.eth.signTransaction)
      const {raw} = await web3.eth.signTransaction(
        txParams, 'my private key is here'
      )
      console.log(raw)
      console.log('sending transaction...')
      const sentTransaction = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw)
```

I've used MetaMask to connect using the same RPC address and chain ID and it worked as intended, and I was able to send transactions.